# How to retrieve Microsoft Azure ACS claims from Facebook as Identity Provider

Tags: facebook-graph-api, azure, acs

this is my first ever proper post, apologies for breaking any formatting conventions.

I am working on a simple app that is using the Microsoft Azure ACS for authentication and Facebook as the Identity Provider. At the moment this is just a index.php page which echoes out a big HTML chunk rendering the login page and accessing the Facebook API.

So far I have been able to set up my ACS account with the correct settings and successfully add Facebook as an identity provider. I am able to login with Facebook and return to my app, as well as use the Facebook API to get information about the user. However, I would like to get the original claims generated by ACS back from Facebook, like the "AccessToken" and "emailaddress" which are set in the ACS management, so that I can later provide this token back to ACS and continue with authentication. I cannot seem to find how to do this anywhere in the Microsoft Doc or Facebook API.

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using ACS as Microsoft is discontinuing it. You should either consider integrating directly with FB (multiple frameworks for this, and quite a bit of docs if you search for it), or consider using an alternative to ACS like [Auth0](https://auth0.com).

Disclaimer: I work in Auth0.